# Vector projection on space

Tags: linear-algebra

There's a question i just can not understand and i need help with her:
we have 4 points, $(0,y1),(1,y2),(3,y3),(4,y4))$ 
and $ y=x−3$ is the line of the 4 points(that we received by least squares).
i need to calculate the projection of $\vec y=(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)$ on space
$W=SP\left\{\left(0,1,3,4\right),\left(1,1,1,1\right)\right\}$
To calculate normally i need the y values,but I can not find a way to find them.
Thank you

Comment: Instead of substituting the (unknown) values, just write down the formula with letters $y_1,\dots,y_4$. Anyway, the problem statement is not clear.

Comment: Yes but what I get an equation with unknown y's.
I guess there's the line $ y=x−3 $ to use it as well

Comment: I don't understand $W$. Are we working in a 4d space?

Comment: @Berci yes,If I understand correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exercise is about understanding the line of best least-square fit as a projection problem.

If you denote $\vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\3 \\ 4\end{pmatrix}$, $\vec{1}=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$   and
$\vec{y}=\begin{pmatrix}y_1 \\ y_2 \\y_3 \\ a_4\end{pmatrix}$, then the line $y=ax+b$ of best least-square fit means

$$||\vec y - (a\vec x + b\vec 1)||_2^2 \text{ is minimal}$$

So, $a\vec x + b\vec 1$ is the orthogonal projection of $\vec y$ onto the span of $\vec x$ and $ \vec 1$.

Since $a=1$ and $b=-3$ are given, you get

$$a\vec{x}+b\vec{1}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\3 \\ 4\end{pmatrix}-3\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-3 \\ -2 \\0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: Only the last line is not clear to me,why did we take a=1  and b=−3?

Comment: @NFLX : These are the coefficients of the line $y=x-3$. And at the same time, these are the coefficients of $\vec x$ and $\vec 1$ which minimize the square distance of $\vec y$ to the span of  $\vec x$ and $\vec 1$.

Comment: Thank you now that's understandable

Comment: You are welcome. :-)